# Trying to reference time from another script using Timespan - Very Confused

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, time

So I had followed a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4t2c1_Szdk) on how to create a day and night cycle in unity and then I wanted to create a menu that appears at about 8 pm in-game showing that the shift had finished but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I have to reference from this script this is the script. I'm seriously lost after looking up countless things online. Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class TimeController : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private float timeMultiplier;

[SerializeField]
private float startHour;

[SerializeField]
private TextMeshProUGUI timeText;

[SerializeField]
private Light sunLight;

[SerializeField]
public float sunriseHour;

[SerializeField]
public float sunsetHour;

[SerializeField]
private Color dayAmbientLight;

[SerializeField]
private Color nightAmbientLight;

[SerializeField]
private AnimationCurve lightChangeCurve;

[SerializeField]
private float maxSunLightIntensity;

[SerializeField]
private Light moonLight;

[SerializeField]
private float maxMoonLightIntensity;

public Material skyboxOne;
public Material skyboxTwo;

public DateTime currentTime;

public TimeSpan sunriseTime;

public TimeSpan sunsetTime;

private FinalScoreMenu ScoreMenu;

public int Hour { get; }

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    currentTime = DateTime.Now.Date + TimeSpan.FromHours(startHour);

    sunriseTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(sunriseHour);
    sunsetTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(sunsetHour);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    UpdateTimeOfDay();
    RotateSun();
    UpdateLightSettings();

}

public void UpdateTimeOfDay()
{
    currentTime = currentTime.AddSeconds(Time.deltaTime * timeMultiplier);

    if (timeText != null)
    {
        timeText.text = currentTime.ToString("HH:mm");
    }
}

private void RotateSun()
{
    float sunLightRotation;

    if (currentTime.TimeOfDay > sunriseTime && currentTime.TimeOfDay < sunsetTime)
    {
        TimeSpan sunriseToSunsetDuration = CalculateTimeDifference(sunriseTime, sunsetTime);
        TimeSpan timeSinceSunrise = CalculateTimeDifference(sunriseTime, currentTime.TimeOfDay);

        double percentage = timeSinceSunrise.TotalMinutes / sunriseToSunsetDuration.TotalMinutes;

        sunLightRotation = Mathf.Lerp(0, 180, (float)percentage);
        RenderSettings.skybox = skyboxOne;
    }
    else
    {
        TimeSpan sunsetToSunriseDuration = CalculateTimeDifference(sunsetTime, sunriseTime);
        TimeSpan timeSinceSunset = CalculateTimeDifference(sunsetTime, currentTime.TimeOfDay);

        double percentage = timeSinceSunset.TotalMinutes / sunsetToSunriseDuration.TotalMinutes;

        sunLightRotation = Mathf.Lerp(180, 360, (float)percentage);
        RenderSettings.skybox = skyboxTwo;
    }

    sunLight.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(sunLightRotation, Vector3.right);
}

private void UpdateLightSettings()
{
    float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(sunLight.transform.forward, Vector3.down);
    sunLight.intensity = Mathf.Lerp(0, maxSunLightIntensity, lightChangeCurve.Evaluate(dotProduct));
    moonLight.intensity = Mathf.Lerp(maxMoonLightIntensity, 0, lightChangeCurve.Evaluate(dotProduct));
    RenderSettings.ambientLight = Color.Lerp(nightAmbientLight, dayAmbientLight, lightChangeCurve.Evaluate(dotProduct));
}

private TimeSpan CalculateTimeDifference(TimeSpan fromTime, TimeSpan toTime)
{
    TimeSpan difference = toTime - fromTime;

    if (difference.TotalSeconds < 0)
    {
        difference += TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    }

    return difference;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Is this the full script? It kind of looks like the Hour property was intended for that purpose but I don’t see anything that updates it.

Anyway, as far as I can see you should be able to check for a specific hour this way:

```
TimeSpan eventTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(eventHour); //20 for 8pm

if (currentTime.TimeOfDay > eventTime )
    // Handle the event and disable this check until the next day.
```

Comment: omg you legend it actually works now, perfect tysm I was stuck at this for so long

Comment: No problem. `TimeSpan.FromHours()` takes a double so you can also do `TimeSpan.FromHours(20.5)` for 8:30pm etc.